# CMD or batch script to export csv column to text file?

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I have this csv file which is too large to open in openoffice, so I was wondering if there's a way to use CMD or a batch script or something like that to copy the contents of a particular column of the csv to a text file.

Comment: Show us a small sample. The vaguer you are, the less help you can expect. The short answer is "possibly - it may depend on your data"

Comment: Use csved for this. And please learn how to ask proper questions here or you will keep collecting -1

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "something like that" includes using a third party application you can use csved (http://csved.sjfrancke.nl) for such tasks.

Comment: Looks like it'll do what I need, thanks.

Comment: @user6851996 , if this answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a vbscript

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'create a new text file
    Set objInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile("input.csv", 1)
    Set objOutput = objFSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)

    while not objInput.AtEndOfStream
            line = objInput.ReadLine

            if line <> "" then
                cols = Split(line, ",", 2)
                objOutput.WriteLine(cols(0))
            end if

    wend

    objOutput.Close
    objInput.Close
```